# EPPlus - InsertRow: Row cannot be less than 1. Parameter name: value

Tags: c#, epplus

I have an Excel template that has a table (range: A4:AM5) which I need to expand by inserting rows via EPPlus. My code inserts the cell values in the file with no problem, but I need to extend the rows of the table according to each new value inserted in the first column.

I tried to use the `InsertRow(5,1)` method but it shows an exception

> "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Row cannot be less than 1.
>   Parameter name: value'"

And the value presents:

> {System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Row cannot be less than 1. Parameter name: value > at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelCellAddress.set_Row(Int32 value) > at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelNamedRangeCollection.InsertRows(Int32 rowFrom, Int32 rows, ExcelNamedRange namedRange) > at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelNamedRangeCollection.Insert(Int32 rowFrom, Int32 colFrom, Int32 rows, Int32 cols, Func`2 filter) > at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet.InsertRow(Int32 rowFrom, Int32 rows, Int32 copyStylesFromRow) > at TestInsertRow.Program.Main(String[] args)}

I minimized the functions of the code into this one which also shows the same exception:

```
    class Dnp3
{
    private static ExcelPackage _dnp3Package;
    private static ExcelWorksheet _worksheet1;
    private static FileInfo _templateInfo;
    private static FileInfo _newDnp3FileInfo;

    public static bool TempFile
    {
        get
        {
            if (_templateInfo != null) return true;
            return false;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value == true)
            {
                _templateInfo = new FileInfo(@" Existing template path ");
            }
        }
    }

    public static bool NewFile
    {
        get
        {
            if (_newDnp3FileInfo != null) return true;
            return false;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value == true)
            {
                _newDnp3FileInfo = new FileInfo(@" Existing new file path ");

                _dnp3Package = new ExcelPackage(_newDnp3FileInfo, _templateInfo);
                {
                    _worksheet1 = Dnp3._dnp3Package.Workbook.Worksheets["DNP3_RTUs"];
                    {
                        _worksheet1.DataValidations.Clear();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static bool Save
    {
        set
        {
            if (value == true)
            {
                Dnp3._dnp3Package.Save();
            }
        }
    }

    public class DNP3_RTUs : Dnp3
    {
        private int _idobj_nameCol;//IDOBJ_NAME
        private int _idobj_aliasCol;//IDOBJ_ALIAS
        private int _idobj_customidCol;//IDOBJ_CUSTOMID
        private int _idobj_aorgroupCol;//IDOBJ_AORGROUP

        public bool Header
        {
            set
            {
                int _column = 1;
                _idobj_nameCol = 1;
                _idobj_aliasCol = 1;
                _idobj_customidCol = 1;
                _idobj_aorgroupCol = 1;

                if (value == true)
                {

                    while (_worksheet1.Cells[Row: 3, Col: _column].Value != null)
                    {
                        switch (_worksheet1.Cells[Row: 3, Col: _column].Value)
                        {
                            case "IDOBJ_NAME":
                                _idobj_nameCol = _column;
                                break;
                            case "IDOBJ_ALIAS":
                                _idobj_aliasCol = _column;
                                break;
                            case "IDOBJ_CUSTOMID":
                                _idobj_customidCol = _column;
                                break;
                            case "IDOBJ_AORGROUP":
                                _idobj_aorgroupCol = _column;
                                break;
                        }
                        _column++;
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        public bool AddRow(int _line)
        {
            _line = _line + 5;
            _worksheet1.InsertRow(_line, 2);
            return false;
        }

        public string IDOBJ_NAME(int _line, string _data)
        {
            _line = _line + 5;//Pq a entrada de dados começa na linha
            _worksheet1.Cells[_line, _idobj_nameCol].Value = _data;
            _worksheet1.Cells[_line, _idobj_nameCol].Style.Font.Size = 11;
            _worksheet1.Cells[_line, _idobj_nameCol].Style.Font.Name = "Calibri";
            return "";
        }

        public string IDOBJ_ALIAS(int _line, string _data)
        {
            _line = _line + 5;//Pq a entrada de dados começa na linha 5
            _worksheet1.Cells[_line, _idobj_aliasCol].Value = _data;
            _worksheet1.Cells[_line, _idobj_aliasCol].Style.Font.Size = 11;
            _worksheet1.Cells[_line, _idobj_aliasCol].Style.Font.Name = "Calibri";
            return "";
        }

        public string IDOBJ_CUSTOMID(int _line, string _data)
        {
            _line = _line + 5;//Pq a entrada de dados começa na linha 5
            _worksheet1.Cells[_line, _idobj_customidCol].Value = _data;
            _worksheet1.Cells[_line, _idobj_customidCol].Style.Font.Size = 11;
            _worksheet1.Cells[_line, _idobj_customidCol].Style.Font.Name = "Calibri";
            return "";
        }

        public string IDOBJ_AORGROUP(int _line, string _data)
        {
            _line = _line + 5;//Pq a entrada de dados começa na linha 5
            _worksheet1.Cells[_line, _idobj_aorgroupCol].Value = _data;
            _worksheet1.Cells[_line, _idobj_aorgroupCol].Style.Font.Size = 11;
            _worksheet1.Cells[_line, _idobj_aorgroupCol].Style.Font.Name = "Calibri";
            return "";
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dnp3.TempFile = true;
        Dnp3.NewFile = true;

        Dnp3.DNP3_RTUs dNP3_RTUs = new Dnp3.DNP3_RTUs() { Header = true };
        int _mappingCount = 1;

            dNP3_RTUs.IDOBJ_NAME(_mappingCount, "BOQ_1");

            dNP3_RTUs.IDOBJ_ALIAS(_mappingCount,"nome_se_ordem");

            dNP3_RTUs.IDOBJ_AORGROUP(_mappingCount, "mnem_se");

        dNP3_RTUs.AddRow(_mappingCount);

        Dnp3.Save = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile so did you copy-paste or did you rewrite the code? You will need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I have make a minimized version of the code which still has the same exception and edited the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f)

Comment: Sorry @VDWWD but I still don't see how to fix it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I faced the same exception and was able to resolve it by fixing the excel template names collection.

Press Ctrl+F3 (Name Manager) and search for names containing any #REF! values and referrers and delete them from the template.

Answer (score 3):

If Ctrl + F3 doesn't work for finding Name Manager

Hover over "sheet.Names" you will find all Name Managers And
you can remove them throw code

```
var refName = sheet.Names.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "nameOfNameManager");
if (refName != null)
{
    sheet.Names.Remove("nameOfNameManager");
}
```